# Where can we go near Paris to watch a meteor shower?

Tags: paris, camping, space

We'll visit Paris next Saturday, and there'll be a meteor peak during the night. Are there any camping areas where the sky will be dark and away from light pollution? It doesn't necessarily have to be a camping facility, but a place where we can spend the night. 
We'll be traveling by car and we can go up to 2 hours away from city center.

Comment: What distance? What methods of transportation do you have? How many time can you spend on travel? This question needs a lot more information to be answerable.

Comment: There are several 'regional parks' surrounding Paris. All of them have campsites, and uninterupted views of the heavens. I'd pick Chevreuse because it means you can visit Versailles en route.

Comment: How to avoid light near the city of light? A hard one indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no actual experience stargazing in France, but nobody answered, so I'll try.

Here's a picture of most of France at night:
[image: France at night]
Source: [www.nightearth.com](http://www.nightearth.com/?@47.771214,4.388649,6.727700626063363z&data=$bWVsMg==&lang=en)

The dark areas have minimal light polution, and a relatively dark area is seen south of Paris. By looking at Google Maps, this seems like the area between Orléans and Vierzon, on either side of the A71 road.

According to [about-france.com](http://about-france.com/regions/region-centre.htm) this area is called La Sologne, and is popular with hunters, nature-lovers and hikers.

According to Google Maps, driving time from Paris to the area is about 1:45 hours.

Of course, you'll need to find a good spot in there - away from lights and without trees blocking the view, and where spending the night is possible and legal. Good luck.